# Make a field a dropdown with values EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a field in the Database like `[OrderDay]` which is of the type `nvarchar(3)`  I have used the EF core to scaffold the Model, Views and Controller. Now the field allows the users to freely type any values as it is `<input>`

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Order Day</label>
            <input asp-for="OrderDay" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OrderDay" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Below is the Model Cass

```
public partial class Setting
{
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string OrderDay { get; set; }
    public int SettingsId { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible I can change the `<input>` to be a dropdown and build the values of the dropdown with in the application like it to hold like ('MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI'). I able to find binding the dropdown with the Database but in the DB I dont have the table to hold this data instead I need to handle with in the application. Is this doable, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Add your list to the model class and bind to that.  Check out these docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-select-tag-helper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form:

```
<select asp-for="OrderDay" class="form-control"></select>
```

Your model class:

```
public partial class Setting
{
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public List<string> OrderDay { get; } = new List<string> {
         "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri" 
        } ;
    public int SettingsId { get; set; }
}
```